# Error with getJSON to load json data file locally on chrome

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, cross-platform, getjson

I'm working on a cross platform (html5) project to be launched on Android and iOS later and I got a problem with `getJSON` to load data from a .json file locally on chrome browser. When calling

```
jQuery.getJSON("layout.json", this.onLoaded);
```

I get

> Error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/app/layout.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https`

at jquery-3.2.1.js:9566 which is: `xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );`

I've surfed the internet looking for solutions and came up with these two solutions that are not working in my case:

1. Enabling access-control-allow-origin manually on chrome
2. Upload the project files on a server

I'm looking for a solution to load the json data locally.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please add some code samples from your project to get help.

Comment: 1. use `HBuilder` this eclipse clone IDE and view local files automatic in a local web server or 2. thread JSON as js file and change it back when you use it in production environments

Comment: @arturkin here is the code sample and the error I got: 

jQuery.getJSON("layout.json", this.onLoaded);

Error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/app/layout.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

jquery-3.2.1.js:9566  which is: xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );

Comment: @YuJiaao thanks for your input. The problem is I want a solution away from running the project on a server even locally.

Comment: inserted the code example from the author's comment; improved formatting.

Please clarify: does "load locally" mean that both the page that loads and the file that is loaded are local?

Comment: Thanks @YakovL for your input and updating my post. I tried to edit it but I couldn't. I meant that they are running locally on PC without any host or server.

Answer (score 1):

this chrome extension helped me with the same problem in chrome, check it out **Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: ***

Comment: Thanks jNg. Yes, this works fine but I work on a cross platform project so is there an alternative in such case? Could I allow this chrome policy using a javascript?

Comment: I can't tell, but I'll do some research

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a cross-browser solution since it is a security measure to protect user's data and browsers' verndors actually block this by intention. In Chrome you may use the `--allow-file-access-from-files` option when launching it but this is not a thing an ordinary user will accept and also there's (somewhy) no way to limit that preference for certain files only, hence this causes security issues again.

Still, if you create a *local* server, put the file you'd like to load *and* the page which is loading the file on the server, this becomes possible. This is quite feasible, there's a number of local servers for Android and probably for other OSes.

PS you can also create a browser extension. Since Chromium extensions are supported by many browsers these days (Opera, Vivaldi, Yandex etc) and even by FireFox, it may be an interesting option. But you have to learn the exact limitations of extensions, I'm not an expert in this area.